# FindBugs eclipse plugin classes location

Tags: eclipse-plugin, findbugs

Is it possible to specify the classes location like you can in the findbugs ant task?

or is there another way to exclude a directory of class files 
(we compile our test classes to a different directory and don't want to use findbugs on those)

P.V. Goddijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through te source of the Eclipse Findbugs plug-in i found its currently impossible to do this (without modifying the Findbugs plug-in).

the plug-in does either a findbugs run over a single class file after a change has been made or a complete run over all the classes as defined by the eclipse project.